# JBoss Library, ClassNotFoundException and the Other Problems

Tags: java, jboss

We were using tomcat for our projects here and we started to think of using JBoss. But i couldnt manage to run any of our projects. I tried to solve the errors, looking for them all over the internet but when i solve an error, the other error comes after it. Im tired of which library should i remove not to clash with JBoss own libraries, hibernate jars, richfaces jars or whatever. Anyone has an ultimate solution for this situation? Im really starting to give up.

By the way, im trying jboss 5.

Comment: There is no "ultimate solution". You have to solve the problems one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd take the opposite approach: remove everything and add which is missing.

I'd start by moving all external libraries  to an "external jars" directory, move back jars which are surely not found in JBoss (you can check `$JBOSS/common/lib`, `$JBOSS/lib`, `$JBOSS/server/<yourtype>/lib` directories). If you ever need to use Tomcat again, I'd copy the "external jars" directory contents to `$TOMCAT/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually pain when you mix up your own webapp libraries with container shared libraries. I would suggest to remove all the shared libraries and try to run it having all the proper jars in your webapp. Once this work you might move on ... If you have any remaining specific problems go ahead and post it :)